# Can Adobe Version Cue CS4 be installed on Windows Server OS

Tags: windows-server-2008, adobe-cs4

I have Windows Server 2008 installed on my office server, I would like to know if i can install Adobe Version Cue on it. So I can use Adobe Version Cue server on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see why not. I suspect that you are kind of supposed to do that anyway.

Various posts on the Adobe forums seem to suggest that people have been doing this without problems.